# Combining rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, r

I have data like:

```
ID     Code1     Procedures1     Code2     Procedure2
001   1          a, b, c         NA        NA
001   NA         NA              2         x, y, z
```

And i would like it to look like this:

```
ID     Code1     Procedures1     Code2     Procedure2
001   1          a, b, c         2         x, y, z
```

I tried different versions of concat as well as groupings and it didnt seem to work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show your table structure please.

Comment: Hi Jorge, Sorry i dont think I can because it is proprietary.  Should i maybe make up an example table?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Update MyTable a
(inner join select * from MyTable) b on a.ID=b.ID
set a.Code1=case when a.Code1 is not null then Code1 else Code2 end,
    a.Procedures1=case when a.Procedures1 is not null then a.Procedures1 else b.Procedures2 end,
    a.Code2=case when a.Code2 is not null then a.Code2 else b.Code2 end,
    a.Procedures2 =case when a.Procedures2 is not null then a.Procedures2 else b.Procedures2 end
```

and after that remove the duplicated of just running

```
select distinct * from My_Table
```

Comment: Would there be a way to maybe do this in R?  I can export this data to there.

Comment: yes but i can't think on any simple solution in R , i have add R maybe you will receive answer for that, but i think its much more simple in SQL, you can duplicate your table if you don't want to change your source table.